# Concurrently reading/writing onto three physical drives OK?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning

There are three physical drives on my PC. One of the drive is partitioned into C: and D:. The other two are E: and F:.

Is it OK to do SFC or CHKDSK concurrently on all three physical drives? I understand that it is not a good idea to do SFC or CHKDSK on C: and D: concurrently because they are actually one drive. Doing so on both of the partitions at the same time would incur too much stress on the drive.

I think it is OK to do SFC or CHKDSK on all three physical drives concurrently, provided only C: or D:, but not both, is running the command. Still, I'd like to get confirmation or I'd risk ruin my drives.

Comment: Why not just do one at a time? Is there some reason why you **need** to run chkdsk on all your drives?

Comment: @DavidPostill, It'd save time if the commands can be run on all three drives concurrently. Two of the drives are 2 TB drives. It'd take a while for the command to finish. Running CHKDSK, and SFC, is just for maintenance. I typically run SFC once a month and CHKDSK every six months or so.

Comment: "Too much stress".. don't worry about that.. but it will take a LOT LONGER.  MORE THAN twice as long making it pointless.

Comment: @ Señor CMasMas, I hope you're right but I have had tossed away two external USB drives because I often watched two videos (why? really) concurrently on the same drive. I thus suspect doing so would damage  the drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can , the cpu/chipset & operating system handles the I/O operations and time scheduling too.

Comment: I hate when I type something stupid then have to delete it.  This is a very good answer.